# Send parameter from script to servlet with POST

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have JavaScript code associated to a web focus process that return me some parameter. I want to pass one of those parameters to my Servlet, but I don't know how I can pass this parameter to my servlet. I paste some code down:

```
document.form1.INFCENTRO.value=9991;
document.form1.NOMBRENTI.value='DOCALIA';
document.form1.NOMBRENTI.disabled=true;
document.form1.NOMAPE.disabled=true;
document.form1.CLAVEUSU.value=user_espe;
document.form1.CLAVEUSU.disabled=true;
document.form1.FECHAPETI.disabled=true;

var pagina="http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTipoPapel";

function redireccionar() 
{
    location.href=pagina;
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 20);
```

In `document.form1.CLAVEUSU` I obtain the value that I want to pass to my Servlet, but I don't know how... can somebody help me?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder May be he meant "doubt" :D

Comment: @asifsid88 you also misspelled it yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard lolz .. my bad :P :D

Comment: @asifsid88 doesn't matter, dude or doubt it's noise so I removed it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nice :)

Comment: sry for my bad english...the problem is that sometimes is easy to mistake with some words.. i hate false friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to post that form. If so:

```
function redireccionar() {
    document.form1.method = "POST"; // Don't need this if it's in the markup
    document.form1.action = "http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTipoPapel"; // Could put this in the markup as well
    document.form1.submit();
}

setTimeout(redireccionar, 20);
```

But you'll need to **not** disable the form elements (remove `document.form1.CLAVEUSU.disabled=true` and such) because disabled form elements aren't sent with forms.

---

Note that it's usually best *not* to use strings with `setTimeout`. I've used a function reference above.

Comment: Correct but he still won't send any values as he disable the form elements. Worth to mention this as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks, I didn't see the lines setting `disabled`.

Comment: Thanks i think that with that is enough, i will try now all, thanks very much.

Comment: @Deckard27: De nada. Espero que ayude.

Answer (score 0):

With your "redirecionar" function, your browser will do a GET request to the "pagina" URL, not a POST. So the server will never receive your parameters from the form

There are 2 workarounds I think:

1) Keep GET method, but add parameters to the URL through appending

```
"?INFOCENTRO=9991&NOMBRENTI=DOCALTA..."
```

Be carefull to URL escape your variables.

2) Use a POST method with a piece of code as follows:

```
function redireccionar() 
{
   document.form1.action = pagina;
   document.form1.submit();
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 20);
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Thanks jejeje is similar to the solution apport by Crowder

Comment: Yep sorry, was posting at the same moment !